# asp.net MVC New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC site. When I run my project on my laptop, it works well
but when I run it on the server, this error occurs:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

This my controller code :

```
var studentList = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update Barcode set PID = '"+nPID+ "' ,TID='"+nTID+ "' , DateT = '"+nDateT+ "' where (PID = "+PID+ " AND TID = "+TID+ " AND DateT = '"+ DateT + "' )");
db.SaveChanges();
```

Please help me

Comment: Where did you get "db" from? Is it an injected variable? Did you construct the repository instance yourself as part of the request?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: That's all the code you are including?

Comment: In IIS manager click on the application in the tree.

Double click ASP under the IIS section.

Expand "Debugging Properties"

Ensure both "Enable Client-side Debugging" and "Enable Server-side debugging" are set to false.

When debugging is enabled ASP is limited to processing one request at a time in a single threaded manner.

Comment: Please include snippets around `db.SaveChanges()`. Is that contains a loop? The message indicates that you're initating a new transaction while current data connection is still serving other tasks, e.g. iteration.

Comment: code is ok in my pc but in server give me error.